# How to select the last element within an element regardless of type in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select the last nested element regardless of the element's type.

Example:

```
<section>
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    <div></div> <-- I want this element
</section>
<section>
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    <a></a>     <-- I want this element
</section>
<section>
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    <ul>        <-- I want this element
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

How do I get these elements? `:last-child` doesn't seem to do the trick and `:last-of.type` is also not helpful because I have to specify which type of element I want.

I want the last nested element of the `section` elements.

Comment: ":last-child doesn't seem to do the trick" Are you sure about that? How are you using it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this:

```
section > *:last-child {
    // your custom css styles
}
```

**Explanation:**

This works because when you use:

`>` it select the immediate children

`*` this selects all the the elements

`nth-child` ensures that all the immediate children will be targetted (if you use `nth-of-type` that is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

you can use  `section >*:last-child` where `*` is the universal selector and `>` is the child selector, meaning only will apply to the direct descendants of `section`

```css
section {
  color: blue
}
section > *:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>blue</div>
  <p>blue</p>
  <div>red</div>
  <!-- I want this element -->

</section>
<section>
  <div>blue</div>
  <p>blue</p>
  <a>red</a>
  <!-- I want this element -->

</section>
<section>
  <div>blue</div>
  <p>blue</p>
  <ul>
    <!-- I want this element -->

    <li>red</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```